# What impact does the lambda section have in this list comprehension?

Tags: python, lambda, list-comprehension

According to the syntax specification of comprehension ,`[x for x in (1,2,3) if lambda x :x-2]` is valid. However,`[x for x in (1,2,3)]`has the same result .What impact does the **lambda** section have in this list comprehension?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has no impact. The `lambda` expression defines a `function` object, and the `if` guard in a list comprehension expects a Boolean value. The "truthiness" of a `function` object is always `True`, so the list comprehension is exactly the same as

```
[x for x in (1,2,3) if True]
```

If you actually *called* the resulting function, such as with

```
[x for x in (1,2,3) if (lambda y :y-2)(x)]
```

then you would have an actual filter that effectively checks if a value is not equal to 2. (`y - 2` will be non-zero, and thus `True`, for any value of `y` other than 2.)